# Finding right triangles in Lisp

Tags: common-lisp

I was skimming "Learn You a Haskell" and found, at the very bottom of [this page](http://learnyouahaskell.com/starting-out#im-a-list-comprehension), a way of finding a triple (a, b, c) representing a right triangle with a specified perimeter that I found very elegant --

```
ghci> let rightTriangles' = [ (a,b,c) | c <- [1..10], b <- [1..c], a <- [1..b], a^2 + b^2 == c^2, a+b+c == 24]
```

and I was wondering if there's a way to do this in Lisp in a similar way/without explicitly using loops. Here's what I did --

```
(defun sq (x) (expt x 2))

(loop for c from 1 to 10 do
    (loop for a from 1 to c do
       (let ((b (- 24 a c)))
          (if (= (sq c) (+ (sq a) (sq b)))
              (format t "~a, ~a, ~a~%" a b c)))))
```

but it obviously doesn't look as nice as the Haskell version and it also prints out the solution twice ((6, 8, 10) and (8, 6, 10)) because `a` goes from 1 to `c`.

Comment: Well, the Haskell code doesn't compute b the way you do. It actually loops c from 1 to 10, b from 1 to c, and a from 1 to b. (OK, it doesn't loop, it generates sequences.) That explains why the Haskell only prints one solution while your LISP generates two.

Comment: There's no builtin function for generating sequences in LISP; you can do it with tail recursion but using loop is easier to read and probably a bit more efficient. You could imitate the Haskell with a function *(defun sequence (a b) (loop for i from a to b collect i))*

Comment: If you add to the the outer loop a `named outer` and have in the true condition`(return-from outer)`, that would make it *logically* correct. But ugly.

Comment: Well, Lisp does not natively have list comprehensions like Haskell or Python. But if you really need them, you could build a MACRO that does the job. Its use would definitely look as elegant as the Haskell solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I couldn't resist giving this a try since I wrote a toy library for set theory in CL.
See http://repo.or.cz/w/flub.git/blob/HEAD:/bachelor-cs/set-theory.lisp.

```
(use-package '(:alexandria :bachelor-cs.set-theory))

(defun triangles (h)
  (let ((range (iota h :start 1)))
    (∩ (× (× range range) range)
       (lambda (triangle)
         (destructuring-bind ((a b) c) triangle
           (>= c b a))))))

(defun perimeter (n)
  (lambda (triangle)
    (destructuring-bind ((a b) c) triangle
      (= n (+ a b c)))))

(defun right-triangles (triangle)
  (destructuring-bind ((a b) c) triangle
    (= (* c c) (+ (* a a) (* b b)))))

(∩ (∩ (triangles 10) (perimeter 24)) #'right-triangles) ↦ (((6 8) 10))
```

The ugly bit in this is the representation of triangles as '((a b) c) because of the set operations being defined as binary. So yeah now I got a nice riddle to solve: Define the set operations for variable parameter lists.

Cheers,
max

EDIT: I made the set operations n-ary. Now it can be written like this:

```
(∩ (× (iota 10 :start 1) (iota 10 :start 1) (iota 10 :start 1))
   (lambda (tri)
     (destructuring-bind (a b c) tri
       (>= c b a)))
   (lambda (tri)
     (destructuring-bind (a b c) tri
       (= 24 (+ a b c))))
   (lambda (tri)
     (destructuring-bind (a b c) tri
       (= (+ (* a a) (* b b)) (* c c)))))
```

If you add a simple macro →

```
(defmacro → (args &rest body)
  (let ((g!element (gensym "element")))
    `(lambda (,g!element)
       (destructuring-bind ,args ,g!element
         ,@body))))
```

you come pretty close to the Haskell version in terms of readability imho:

```
(∩ (× (iota 10 :start 1) (iota 10 :start 1) (iota 10 :start 1))
   (→ (a b c) (>= c b a))
   (→ (a b c) (= 24 (+ a b c)))
   (→ (a b c) (= (+ (* a a) (* b b)) (* c c))))
```

Comment: Nice touch using the familiar ,g! syntax with the explicit gensym so that defmacro! didn't have to be mentioned.

Comment: Heh. Yeah the bang syntax is whats left from my use of defmacro!, I found it's abstraction inclomplete in the end. I think it didn't handle nested lambda lists well. There were some rather hairy cases but I don't remember exactly. Should be fixable.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a (recursive) macro to get access to list comprehensions:

```
(defmacro lcomp-h (var domain condition varl)
   (if (= 1 (length var))
     `(loop for ,(car var) from ,(caar domain) to ,(cadar domain) 
          when ,condition
          collect (list ,@varl))
      `(loop for ,(car var) from ,(caar domain) to ,(cadar domain) append
      (lcomp-h ,(cdr var) ,(cdr domain) ,condition ,varl))))

(defmacro lcomp (var domain condition)
  `(lcomp-h ,var ,domain ,condition ,var))
```

Now you have the following syntax:

```
CL-USER> (lcomp (a b c) ((1 10) (a 10) (1 10)) (= (* c c) (+ (* a a) (* b b))))
```

and receive from lisp:

```
((3 4 5) (6 8 10))
```

It took me a while and is surely not complete but seems to work.

Answer (score 1):

You can make the loops less pronounced using `dotimes`instead of loop.

```
(defun right-triangles (circ)
       (dotimes (c (/ circ 2))
         (dotimes (b c)
            (dotimes (a b)
               (when (and (= circ (+ a b c))
                          (= (* c c) (+ (* a a) (* b b))))
                  (format t "~a, ~a, ~a~%" a b c))))))
```

As `(dotimes (i n))` is looping `i`from 0 to `n-1`, `a`, `b`, and `c` will all be different. Thus no isosceles triangle will be found.  However, as no isosceles right triangle exist where all the side lengths are rational numbers, this is not a problem.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution using the constraint-based DSL from the [Screamer](https://github.com/nikodemus/screamer) package ([Quicklisp](http://www.quicklisp.org/) installable):

```
CL-USER>
(in-package :screamer)
#<Package "SCREAMER">
SCREAMER>
(let* ((c (an-integer-betweenv 1 10))
       (b (an-integer-belowv c))
       (a (an-integer-belowv b)))
  (assert! (=v (*v c c)
               (+v (*v a a)
                   (*v b b))))
  (assert! (=v (+v a b c)
               24))
  (one-value
    (solution (list a b c)
              (static-ordering #'linear-force))))
(6 8 10)
```